# Help with GATC and var _gaq = _gaq || [];

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

Here is my GATC. It is located in the FOOTER of my application.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var _gaq = _gaq || [];

  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXX-XX']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mysite.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_addIgnoredRef', 'mysite.com']);
  _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',1,'UserType','Visitor', 2]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

If I want to set some new custom variables in the BODY page, how would I do that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'NewVar','Name', 2]);
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',2,'NewVar','Name', 2]);
</script>
```

To summarize:

I need to define some custom variables in the body of a page and my GATC is in the footer.  I'm not quite sure the meaning of _gaq = _gaq and how it will effect this.  Should it be in the snippet to define the custom variable in the body and then again in the GATC in the footer?

Comment: `_gaq = _gaq || [];` just assigns an empty array to `_gaq` *if* it was previously null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
```

This line uses existing `_gaq` array or creates a new one and assigns to `_gaq` if it hasn't been defined(or contains falsy value). Therefore your first option (containing `_gaq` assignment) is better.